# Looking for a 14 pin FFC, FPC connector for 1.8" display with unused space on the sides

Tags: connector, socket, tft, fpc, ffc

Good evening,

I'm looking for a connector that can house **14-pin connector display**. 
Problem is that it has some extra space on the side which would not fit into regular connector.

Does anyone knows of the model of this specific connector ?

See images below for the display schematic and image.

Thank you.

[image: schematic]
[image]

Comment: ask the supplier of that display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, these type are soldered to pcb directly.Standart FPC/FFC do not have Vias on the gold fingers.

These are soldered directly to a matching footprint on the pcb.

You have the following options:

- Ask Manufacturer for mating connector
- Try to cut the pcb to match a standart connector
- Buy a standart 14-pin cable assembly and solder it on the pcb, then insert the cable in a standart connector.

Comment: Is it safe to cut around cable (assuming that I would not touch any of pins 1-14 ?)

Comment: This depends. For "emergency solution" i would do it. Otherwise i would either look for another display ore use the cable adapter i described